# Finding keys in a hash that do not exist in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, logical-operators

In Ruby, one can find which keys exist in both a hash and an array using the following

```
(hash.keys & array_of_keys)
```

What operator do I need to use in order to find keys in the hash that do not exist in the array?

Answer (score 4):

Simply `hash.keys - array_of_keys`.

```
hash = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
array_of_keys = [:a, :c]

hash.keys - array_of_keys
# => [:b]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2D)

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2}
h.keys - [:c, :b]
# => [:a]
```